# Python Virtual Assistant not continuing after a block of code. while 1:

Tags: function, while-loop, artificial-intelligence

I will provide the code for a portion. It doesn't continue after using commands within a while block. I think it is the code block text = get_audio().lower() that is giving me the error.

```
def process_text():
pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
assistant_speaks('''Hello, I am a Virtual Assistant. 
                I am here to make your life easier. You can command me to perform 
                various tasks such as calculating sums or opening applications. 
                Please tell me who you are.''')
name = 'are'
name = get_audio()
assistant_speaks("Hello, " + name + '.')

while 1:

    assistant_speaks("What can i do for you?" + name + '.')
    text = get_audio().lower()

    if text == 0:
        continue

    if "exit" in str(text) or "bye" in str(text) or "sleep" in str(text):
        assistant_speaks("Ok bye, " + name + '.')
        break

    # calling process text to process the query
        process_text()


    def process_text():
        try:
            if 'search' in input or 'play' in input:
                # a basic web crawler using selenium
                search_web(input)
                return

            elif "who are you" in input or "define yourself" in input:
                speak = '''Hello, I am a virtual assistant. 
                I am here to make your life easier. You can command me to perform 
                various tasks such as calculating sums or opening applications.'''
                assistant_speaks(speak)
                return
```

Basically, it doesn't answer any questions when I ask the elifs. Past the try:

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You should specify a bit better what you mean by "when I ask the elifs": do you mean "when I ask the program 'who are you'"? Anyway your `process_text` function checks a variable `input` that would actually be a built-in Python function.. maybe the problem arises there?

Comment: I don't exactly know. An example would be if I asked "Who are you", then it goes back to the while 1 and asks "what it can do for me". It doesn't answer. I thought that if it detects that input, it would say the preprogrammed output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least three mistakes you should correct in order to get the behavior you want from your program:

- Replace `input` with `text` inside the `try` block. In Python, `input` is a built-in function, not a string. You already assigned the user's answer to the variable `text`, so why not use that one? :)
- Define your `process_text` function *before* you call it. Practically, you should move the line where you call `process_text()` somewhere after the definition of that function.
- There are also a couple of indentation errors, and the most important happens when you call the `process_text()` function: you should un-indent that line back one level, otherwise it will be executed inside the `if "exit" in ...` block.

You should also define `process_text` before the while loop, because you just need to define it once.

Comment: I tried these solutions and they worked for some commands. I am actually working on a more advanced AI now and I am using Weather, Wolframalpha, and News Api's. The only one that works correctly is the wolframalpha api. When i put the Api keys in for the other 2 api's and command to give the news or weather, it just goes back to "Listening..."

Comment: You're welcome, and remember that you can always debug your program by adding  calls to `print` whenever you want to check some variable in your program. Good luck!